# How to add more than one widget to TabPanel GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, widget, tabpanel

With these lines I have added only one widget for Tab Panel:

```
DialogBox popupProperties = new DialogBox();
TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel(); 
HTML label1 = new HTML("<ul><li><b>This is contents of TAB1</b></li</ul>");
label1.setHeight("200");
Label label2 = new Label("This is contents of TAB 2");
label2.setHeight("200");
Label label3 = new Label("This is contents of TAB 3");
label3.setHeight("200");


String tab1Title = "One";
String tab2Title = "Two";
String tab3Title = "Three";    


tabPanel.add(label1,tab1Title);
tabPanel.add(label2,tab2Title);
tabPanel.add(label3,tab3Title);

tabPanel.selectTab(0);

tabPanel.setPixelSize(400, 400); 
popupProperties.add(tabPanel);

popupProperties.setAutoHideEnabled(true);

RootPanel.get().add(popupProperties);
popupProperties.center();
popupProperties.show();
```

I'd like to add label, grid, chart for each Tab.
How can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the docs of TabPanel's [`add()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html#add(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget,%20com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IsWidget)) method.

> Convenience overload to allow IsWidget to be used directly.

So any object of type [IsWidget](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/IsWidget.html), you can add to it, weather it is a Chart, Graph etc ....

[`Example`](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~TabPanel)

Comment: Yes but how can I refer to the same tab? For example [code]tabPanel.add(label1,tab1Title);[/code] refers to the firs tab, so how can I to add any widget to this tab? thanks.

Comment: Yes, i need help with some code example to refer index and add widgets for a specific index.

Comment: @django Added link for a demo and it's source code.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html Example: I'd like to add in tab A, three Label and other widgets, but if I write :[pre]tabPanel.add(label1,tab1Title);tabPanel.add(label2,tab1Title);tabPanel.add(label3,tab1Title);[code] don't works. I don't know to refer to the same tab A to add more widget.I hope I have been clear.

Comment: @django why dont you add your widgets to a `ComplexPanel` like `HorizontalPanel` or `VerticalPanel` and then add the `ComplexPanel` to the `TabPanel`

Comment: @django Have you seen the source code added in example ?

Comment: Yes @sureshatta thank you, now I have understood that my problem was to attach widgets to any panel, so now I have try to use your suggested example with flowpanel and it works! Now my problem is only to override css panel. Sorry but I'm new in GWT.